# ICLRRuntimeHost::ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain fails to execute app

Tags: c#, c++, clr

I've used this code to run my pre-compiled C# application:

```
ICLRMetaHost *p_meta_host = nullptr;
ICLRRuntimeInfo *p_runtime_info = nullptr;
ICLRRuntimeHost *p_clr_runtime_host = nullptr;
CLRCreateInstance(CLSID_CLRMetaHost, IID_PPV_ARGS(&p_meta_host));
p_meta_host->GetRuntime(L"v4.0.30319", IID_PPV_ARGS(&p_runtime_info));
p_runtime_info->GetInterface(CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost,
    IID_PPV_ARGS(&p_clr_runtime_host));
p_clr_runtime_host->Start();
auto hr = p_clr_runtime_host->ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(
    L"C:\\somefolder\\test.exe",
    L"InjectExample.Program",
    L"EntryPoint",
    L"hey!",
    &p_return_value);
```

After the execution `hr` is not `S_OK` and `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`
The point is file surely exists in `'C:\\somefolder\\test.exe'`
Any ideas why this happens?
--UPD. Found that in debugging log:

```
'NetLoader.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\somefolder\test.exe'. 
'NetLoader.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\somefolder\test.exe'. 
'NetLoader.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\somefolder\test.exe'
```

Comment: You will have to improve your error checking.  Using GetLastError() is not correct, that function must only ever be used after a failed Win32 api call.  The HRESULT return value gives you the error code, most managed exceptions get translated to 0x1813xxxx.  Use IErrorInfo to learn more about the specific exception that was raised, beware that you can't get the holy stack trace.  It would be wise to use the debugger so you can see these exceptions and inspect the stack trace, change the Debugger Type to "mixed".

Comment: And neither approach is a good substitute for the app itself properly reporting unhandled exceptions.  Subscribing the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event is never really optional.

Answer (score 0):

Question resolved.
Apparently `hr` was equals to `COR_E_MISSINGMETHOD` or `0x80131513`
Which means I was trying to use wrong method.
More information about return codes can be found here:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/__hresults.cs,c4f0369b78643cb0